# configuring customimport order in checkstyle

Tags: configuration, checkstyle

I want Checkstyle to follow this import order

```
//IntelliJ Configuration
import static all other imports
import java.*
import javax.*
import lombok.*
import com.fasterxml.*
import org.*
<blank_line> //ideal but not required
all other imports
```

when i look at [Import Order configuration](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_imports.html), I don't see any ordering or I am getting confuse ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look closely at the docs I think you can configure it as you want:

```
<module name="ImportOrder">
    <property name="groups" value="java.,javax.,lombok.,com.fasterxml.,org."/>
    <property name="ordered" value="true"/>
    <property name="separated" value="false"/>
    <property name="option" value="above"/>
</module>
```

The only missing part would be lack of blank line after the import groups.